# firebase pubsub function invoked but not writing to firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple pub sub cloud function

```
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});


exports.updateNews = functions.pubsub
  .topic("firebase-schedule-cronForNews-us-central1")
  .onPublish(message => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?apiKey=241414&sources=espn-cric-info"
      )
      .then(result => {
        return result.data.articles.forEach(article => {
          db.collection("news").add(article);
        });
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      });

    return null;
  });
```

The function is being invoked but it is not writing to firestore the same code works when I convert this to http function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try returning the promises chain and using a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes), as follows:

```
exports.updateNews = functions.pubsub
  .topic("firebase-schedule-cronForNews-us-central1")
  .onPublish(message => {
    return axios  // Note the return here
      .get(
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?apiKey=241414&sources=espn-cric-info"
      )
      .then(result => {
        const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
        result.data.articles.forEach(article => {
           const docRef = admin.firestore().collection("news").doc();
           batch.set(docRef, article);
        });
        return batch.commit();
      })
      .then(result => {  // You don't need this then if you don't need the console.log
        console.log(result);  
        return null;
      });
  });
```

Comment: You are welcome. I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/. They very well explain the need to return the promise chain.